# Facing error in mysql Trigger

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating trigger in mysql but I am facing error in it.

What I am trying to do is when status updated and is set to 1 I have to check that buyer also active then and then I have to update status.

```
        DELIMITER //
        CREATE TRIGGER `after_vendor_update` AFTER DELETE ON `data_vendor`
        FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        IF(NEW.vendor_status = 1)
            UPDATE vendor_setting SET  `buyer_setting_status` = NEW.vendor_status WHERE buyerid IN (SELECT bid FROM data_buyer WHERE buyer_status='1');
        ELSE
            UPDATE vendor_setting SET  `buyer_setting_status` = NEW.vendor_status;
        END IF;
        END
        //
        DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: what error are you facing?? please elaborate..

Comment: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE vendor_setting SET `buyer_setting_status` = NEW.vendor_status WHERE buye' at line 4"

Comment: when status is updated in `data_vendor` table I have to check that there is active buyer `data_buyer` table

Comment: plese provide your DB schema as well

Comment: normally i'd be in agreement with the request for schema.. but for a syntax error it's probably not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the `if` statement syntax wrong, it should be:

```
IF NEW.vendor_status = 1 THEN
```